# Problems installing Node and NPM via Homebrew

Tags: terminal, homebrew, permission

As of Monday morning, running the `nodemon` and `npm run dev` commands for a project I'm working on failed, and I traced it to some error with NPM itself.

```
macbookpro@MacBookPro:/usr/local/lib$ npm -v
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:153:3)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js' ]
}
macbookpro@MacBookPro:/usr/local/lib$ node -v
v13.8.0
macbookpro@MacBookPro:/usr/local/lib$ ls -al node_modules/npm/bin/
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 9 macbookpro staff 288B 24 Feb 09:03 ./
drwxr-xr-x 25 root wheel 800B 7 Aug 2019 ../
drwxr-xr-x 4 macbookpro staff 128B 24 Feb 09:03 node-gyp-bin/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 macbookpro staff 893B 24 Feb 09:03 npm*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 macbookpro staff 4.5K 24 Feb 09:03 npm-cli.js*
-rw-r--r-- 1 macbookpro staff 483B 24 Feb 09:03 npm.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 macbookpro staff 887B 24 Feb 09:03 npx
-rwxr-xr-x 1 macbookpro staff 177B 24 Feb 09:03 npx-cli.js*
-rw-r--r-- 1 macbookpro staff 539B 24 Feb 09:03 npx.cmd
macbookpro@MacBookPro:/usr/local/lib$
```

So while Node itself was running, NPM wasn't, in spite of the fact that its file was present.

In development I use `nodemon` and `npm run dev` in two Terminal tabs — both were running Sunday night, before stopping them and then sleeping the Mac.

I was wondering if a permission had been altered.

I tried Homebrew, which installed Node but not NPM, so I had to remove that.

I tried the official Node installer for Mac, but it's an old version that caused problems, so I had to remove that.

I went down the nuclear path, and removed Node wherever it could be found:

```
brew uninstall node;
which node;
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node;
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/
brew doctor;
brew cleanup --prune-prefix
```

I then tried the official instruction to install Node via the command line:

```
curl "https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-${VERSION:-$(wget -qO- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/ | sed -nE 's|.*>node-(.*)\.pkg</a>.*|\1|p')}.pkg" > "$HOME/Downloads/node-latest.pkg" && sudo installer -store -pkg "$HOME/Downloads/node-latest.pkg" -target "/"
```

… which failed:

`-bash: wget: command not found`

… and when I attempted to install wget:

`brew install wget`

… I got more errors:

> Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully The formula
>   built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local Could not symlink
>   share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/libidn2.mo
>   /usr/local/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES is not writable.
>
> You can try again using:   brew link libidn2

… and:

> Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully The formula
>   built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local Could not symlink
>   share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo
>   /usr/local/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES is not writable.
>
> You can try again using:   brew link wget

I had similar problems with Homebrew before the weekend, and I think this is a continuation of that.

When I run `brew doctor` I get:

```
Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/node/...
```

… and there are hundreds of files associated with Node, in spite of having uninstalled it.

I've since found a few different approaches to fix the possible permissions issue:

`sudo chown -R`whoami`:admin /usr/local/`

… and:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`

… but since I have no idea what the possible consequences of running either of these would be, some expert advice would be much welcome!

Comment: ***Going nuclear*** requires a good backup: turn the clock back from 5 past 12 to  [100 seconds before midnight](https://thebulletin.org/doomsday-clock/past-statements/) by restoring your Sunday evening backup. IMHO your /usr/local/ folder is FUBAR.

Comment: Hi @klanomath, I ran Time Machine on Sunday — I'm assuming it's possible to restore hidden folders?

Comment: Check MichelleM's answer first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved this same error. What worked for me was:

```
brew install node
sudo chmod 776 /usr/local/lib
brew link --overwrite node
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/lib
```

When I ran `npm -v` I got the same error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
```

To solve it I ran `brew reinstall node` and everything is running as expected now.

Comment: Hi Michelle, an thanks for the suggestion! The concern I have is changing the permissions on those folders — any thoughts on that?

Comment: I'd check your current permissions on the folder by running ```stat -f %A /usr/local/lib``` and then make sure to change it back to that after running ```brew link --overwrite node``` like I did in my answer :)

Comment: When I ran`brew link --overwrite node` I got: `Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.8.0... 
Error: Could not symlink include/node/common.gypi
/usr/local/include/node is not writable.` Would I need to change permissions there, also?

Comment: Yes I was getting that error as well. I ran ```rm '/usr/local/include/node/config.gypi'``` then followed the steps in my answer.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure which version of node you're running so you may want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-node-version) to make sure you get up and running on the same version you had previously.

Comment: I followed these instructions but it's not worked: `macbookpro@macbookpro:~$ node -v
-bash: node: command not found
macbookpro@macbookpro:~$ npm -v
-bash: npm: command not found
macbookpro@macbookpro:~$ `

Comment: That means node isn't installed. Did you run ```brew install node```?

Comment: Yeah, I ran the commands as per the answer.

Comment: What's the output when you run ```brew install node```?

Comment: `Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
No changes to formulae.

Warning: node 13.8.0 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link node` to link this version.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104881/discussion-between-wayne-smallman-and-michelle-m).

Comment: Next you run ```sudo chmod 776 /usr/local/lib```